# Запрос insert PDO PHP

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Хочу записать все $value в таблицу users столбец lastname. Как?

```html
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'root', '');

foreach ($sample as &$value) {
    $pdo->
}
```

Comment: Преобразуйте массив в строку в формате, который принимает `INSERT .. VALUES`, добавьте начало, и выполните запрос. Цикл - не нужен.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt= $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (lastname) VALUES (?)");

foreach ($sample as $value) {
    $stmt->execute([$value]);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я так делал.Почему то не работает. Такой пример во многих статьях на просторах интернета.

Comment: а что именно не работает?